# Multiple auth in middleware. Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Im new in PHP and Laravel. I try to search online but i cant get the right answer for my problem. I want my specific page accessible only by admin and user that already been authenticated. So basically, all the user need to login first. Heres my code. Thanks in advance.

**HomeController.php**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:web, auth:admin');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('accounts.user.user_dashboard');
    }
}
```

**auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
```

Comment: for your requirement you just only need to create a route middleware to check the users' roles whether the role is normal user or admin user. you can then use web middle ware or admin middleware not both. and normal web can be automatically accessible by admin role user. you dont need to put multiple middleware. and best way is to use on routes not on controller constructor.

Comment: try on your own by defining a route middleware which will check the users role from users table. do simple way not your way... if you can not figure out using route middleware then i will post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

i used this, in route file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function (){
     Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a middleware to check if the user has certain permission or not. Here is how I am used to doing it.

I create a middleware say for example SuperAccess and write my logic for super admin there.

```
class SuperAccess
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->permission == 1000){
        return redirect('web/dashboard');
    }
    return $response;
}
}
```

Then i use the middleware where I need to have superAccess checked for example say in DeviceController

```
class DevicesController extends Controller
{
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('super');
}
```

**Note:** In the example above I have a role table which has a relation with user table.